# Remove trailing characters in line following carriage return

Tags: c, newline, carriage-return

```
int main() {
    printf("test 1234\r");
    printf("bird\n"); //prints bird 1234. I want to only print bird. 
    return 0;
}
```

I would prefer to stick to using the carriage return -- outside of adding a large amount of spaces following "bird", how can I clear the line?

Comment: How about `int n = printf("test 1234\r"); printf("bird%*s", n-4, "\n");`?

Comment: How about printf("\33[2Kbird\n"); as as your second line?  That will erase the entire line your cursor is currently on before printing bird.

Comment: Unless you use special terminal characteristics (beware: terminals differ), you will need to output blanks up to the length of the first string.  The general problem is harder; you have to keep track of all the output and know how many characters have been generated on the line so far, so you can write blanks over them to erase them.